# Running dusk after php artisan serve fails in CircleCI

Tags: laravel, docker, circleci, laravel-dusk

I'm working on a CircleCi config file that runs unit tests and browser (dusk) tests. Tests fail in CircleCi every time on the command php artisan dusk. Php artisan serve also is 'canceled' if I add the attribute `background: true`.

1. Declaring the port `php artisan serve --port=8000`
2. Using `backgroud: true` and `php artisan serve &`
3. Tried running `curl http://localhost:8000` (failed)

circleci config file

```
version: 2

jobs:
  Test:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/php:7.2-fpm-node-browsers
      - image: circleci/redis:5.0
      - image: circleci/mysql:5.7
        environment:
          MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ''
          MYSQL_USER: homestead
          MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
          MYSQL_DATABASE: homestead
          MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: true

    environment:
      APP_ENV: testing
      APP_URL: http://localhost:8000
      APP_KEY: ###

      DB_HOST: 127.0.0.1
      DB_DATABASE: homestead
      DB_USERNAME: homestead
      DB_PASSWORD: secret

      REDIS_HOST: 127.0.0.1
      REDIS_PASSWORD: 'null'

      PUSHER_APP_ID: ###
      PUSHER_APP_KEY: ###
      PUSHER_APP_SECRET: ###
      PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER: ###

      MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY: ###
      MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER: ###

    working_directory: ~/workspace

    steps:
      - checkout

      - run:
          name: Prepare Environment
          command: .circleci/kickstart.sh

      - restore_cache:
          keys:
            - composer-v1-{{ checksum "composer.lock" }}
            - composer-v1-
      - run: composer install -n --prefer-dist
      - save_cache:
          key: composer-v1-{{ checksum "composer.lock" }}
          paths:
            - vendor

      - restore_cache:
          keys:
            - node-v1-{{ checksum "package-lock.json" }}
            - node-v1-
      - run: npm install
      - save_cache:
          key: node-v1-{{ checksum "package-lock.json" }}
          paths:
            - node_modules

      - run:
          name: Build Artifacts
          command: npm run dev

      - run:
          name: Waiting for MySQL to be ready
          command: dockerize -wait tcp://127.0.0.1:3306 -timeout 120s

      - run: php artisan config:clear
      - run: php artisan config:cache
      - run: php artisan migrate:refresh --seed --database=mysql --force
      - run: php artisan dusk:install

      - run:
          name: Run PHP Unit Tests
          command: ./vendor/bin/phpunit

      - run:
          name: Run server
          command: php artisan serve --port=8000 &

      # - run:
      #    name: Run server
      #    command: php artisan serve --port=8000
      #    background: true

      - run:
          name: Test connection to server
          command: curl http://localhost:8000

      - run:
          name: Run E2E Tests
          command: php artisan dusk
          environment:
            APP_URL: http://localhost:8000

      - store_artifacts:
          path: ./tests/Browser/console
          destination: console

      - store_artifacts:
          path: ./tests/Browser/screenshots
          destination: screenshots

workflows:
  version: 2
  Build and Test:
    jobs:
      - Test
```

curl failing

```
#!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
php artisan serve --port=8000 &
curl http://localhost:8000
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8000: Connection refused
Exited with code 7
```

Dusk should run after the server is running

Comment: Dusk is not being tried, because the curl before it is failing. Since you are backgrounding the Artisan command, I wonder whether the curl is started before the listener has fully started? Try putting a `sleep 2` before the curl command.

Comment: The curl statement was for testing purposes, it still fails if I remove the curl command @halfer

Comment: Yes, but the curl in fact is a good idea - keep that permanently, or use `dockerize`/`waitforit` commands to poll until your backgrounded service is ready to service requests. Did you try a `sleep`?

Comment: yes I've tried to use a sleep 5

Comment: Errors look like this: Did not see expected value [Register] within title []. Failed asserting that false is true.

Comment: Do you get that in addition to the curl failure, or does the curl failure now not happen?

Comment: No, if I leave the curl statement then the build fails and dusk is not run

Comment: Great. Leave the curl statement in. The other error probably has the same root cause - your listener has not started up, and thus the tests in Dusk will fail.

Comment: Please edit in where you have put the `sleep 5`. I recommend copying and pasting rather than just editing here, so that you're showing something that you have tried, exactly as you tried it.

Comment: After the `sleep 5`, put in a new command of `ps aux` to see what processes you are running. My guess is that the `artisan serve` command has exited, and it would be good to confirm/reject that suspicion.